# google places sdk migration to new sdk android

Tags: google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places

I received email from google :

> We are writing to remind you that the previous versions of Places SDK for Google Maps Platform were deprecated on January 29, 2019, and will be turned off on July 29, 2019. This email is our final reminder before the previous versions are completely shut off.

```
        List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS);

        Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields)
                .build(activity);

        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, IntentParams.REQUEST_SELECT_PLACE);
```

app level build.gradle:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
```

project level gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

What more changes do I have to do?

Comment: Please ensure that you've followed the [full migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration), that you've removed all Google Play services instances, updated assets and only use new SDK methods etc. If still in doubt please post your full build.gradle and code implementation.

Comment: I have followed migration guide. Updated the question with the gradle file.

Comment: Hey are you using the new SDK? The old one has been turned off by now. Let us know if you are still having issues with the migration.

Comment: It's been 10 days passed after that.. Haven't faced any issue yet.. I guess there's no issue now.. thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear! Thanks for the update.